# Render only html a tag (link) in .cshtml page (razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Example:

`string ChatMessage = "Check this website <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">http://www.example.com</a><script>alert(1);</script><h1>Hi</h1>";`

```
@Html.Raw(ChatMessage)
```

Output

`Check this website http://www.example.comHi";`

I want

`Check this website http://www.example.com<script>alert(1);</script><h1>Hi</h1>";`

I can use @Html.Raw (it is open for JavaScript injections and other html tags).

How can I use @Html.Raw or something else to render only `<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>` in .cshtml page?

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to show the full link address and should it be clickable?

Comment: I want to show full link address and clickable. I have added more information

Comment: you can use  this for render only link `@Html.ActionLink("http://www.example.com", "http://www.example.com")`

Comment: The text is dynamic. I have added more information